# How to display frontend test results and frontend test coverage reports when using S/4HANA Cloud SDK Pipeline

Tags: s4sdk

We have updated our pipeline by using the latest version from:

https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline

But neither the test results nor the test coverage reports of the frontend unit tests could be found.

Could anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried? Please be more specific

Comment: We committed some new changes, trigging a new build of pipeline, which executed some local tests like Backend Unit Tests, Backend Integration Tests, Frontend Unit Tests and Static Code Checks respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory where the tests are has changed to `s4hana_pipeline/reports/` recently. Please update your `karma.conf.js` file as described in https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/19/step-12-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-automated-testing/.

Comment: I found it, the link provided is really informative